# php request with multiple objects json jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to do the following. I have a `mariaDB` server on the run with a database and some tables. Now i want to change the table entrys with a webinterface. So I created the following PHP script.

```
<?php

include '../db/mysql.php';

$line = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `LineDetection`");
$circle = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `CircleDetection`");
$lineArray=array();
$circleArray=array();
while($rowline=mysqli_fetch_assoc($line)){
    $lineArray[]=$rowline;
        }

echo json_encode($lineArray);
echo '<br>';

while($rowcircle=mysqli_fetch_assoc($circle)){
    $circleArray[]=$rowcircle;

}

echo json_encode($circleArray);

mysqli_close($con);
```

The code works fine and returns the following lines.

```
[{"threshold":"10","deltaX":"20","minVal":"50","maxVal":"150"}][{"dp":"5","minDist":"20","cannyThreshold":"10","accThreshold":"112","minRadius":"100","maxRadius":"150"}]
```

My Problem is now that i can't read in the 2 javascript Objects via a get. 1 Object is just fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#PicButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax/get1.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: self.dataElements,
            success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg[0]);
                       }
             });
        });
});
```

Comment: You should try packing both echo's into one object.

Comment: The problem was was that your response was two separate arrays each with one object in, instead of one array with two objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Doug. I did it know with the following code.

```
echo '{"LineDetection":',json_encode($rowline),',"CircleDetection":', json_encode($rowcircle),"}";
```